# Exception of RuntimeBinder Facebook SDK c#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, dynamic, facebook-c#-sdk

I am writing `facebookc# Sdk` program but the issue is that this strange exception occurs

`'Facebook.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'data'` and says that

`'wall.data' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' dynamic {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}`

even orignal samples from website are giving errors. Am I missing something?

I have also added reference to `Microsoft.CSharp` and Using dot net `framework 4.0`

I loked at various links but did not helped

```
   dynamic wall = fb.Get("me/feed");
 List<dynamic> WALL = new List<dynamic>(wall.data);
```

and string in wall is something like (too long pasting short)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Mistake I had included the 3.5 version of SDK it should be 4.0 for `dynamic` usage

Answer (score 0):

this is because the cast that you are trying to make is invalid...

```
 dynamic wall_data = wall.data
```

then you can go through wall_data and get what you want

this appears to be `JSON` , why not just use a JSON library like `JSON.net` and keep it that way !!!

Comment: thanks for reply but i think you missed the picture below which shows the data is there and issue was that I had included the 3.5 dll and chaning it to 4.0 bug was history

Comment: ok..but still just curious to know why you choose dynamic over JSON ?